# Java Impossible puzzler

Tags: java, puzzle

Anyone can get the equation for this? I couldn't

```
class Calculator {
    public int count = 0;
public void calc(int n, int p) {
    count++;
        if (p>n) return;
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            calc(n, p+1);
        }
    }
}

// int n is input by keyboard
Calculator c = new Calculator();
c.calc(n, 0);
System.out.println(c.count);
```

Anybody with the equation or any information?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sure looks like Homework. Hint: It is two different ways to do iterations. Work it out for some small numbers of n. Also, the equation is a very simple expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `count` is incremented once and then calc is called `n` times, this recurses `1 + n` times due to the `p > n` test. BTW If it were `p >= n` it would recurse `n` times.

The equation is

```
1 + n * (1 + n * ... (1 + n))
```

where the expression `1 + n` appears `1 + n` times.

e.g. calc(3,0) = 121 =

```
1 + 3 * (1 + 3 * (1 + 3 * (1 + 3)))
```

Comment: this is correct, beat me to it

Comment: @Richard, by at least 2 seconds. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will call

```
calc(n, 1); // this tree will appear n times
  calc(n, 2); // this tree will appear n times
    calc(n, 3) // this tree will appear n times
      .
       .
      calc(n, n+1) // this call will appear n times
```

Each invocation of `calc` will increment `count`. Calclating the number of calls is equivalent to calculating the number of nodes of a complete n-ary tree of height `n+2` (the root of this tree represents the call `c.calc(n, 0)`). So I think the solution is

```
count = n^0 + n^1 + n^2 + ... + n^n + n^(n+1)
```

Comment: The count for n = 3 is 121, n = 4 is 1365.

Comment: @Peter you are right, my formula for calculating the count of nodes was wrong :) Now it's correct.